# Visual Studio Express 2012 Error in Site.Master "Scripts is not declared"

Tags: asp.net

Hi i am just getting into asp.net and SqlServer although have used asp/oracle in the distant past. 
The following code in the Site.Master file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">        
      <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Throws the Error
1   'Scripts' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.'

I'm very slowly getting to grips with the way asp.net does things and any help that can get me over this little hurdle would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: May be the Scripts directory is not accesible in your project.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i can see the scripts folder in the solution window and the jquery's etc within it. 
I assumed that meant it was accessible in the project. Again i'm new to this am i missing a step here?

Answer (score 3):

This utility is provided by the `System.Web.Optimization` library.  Make sure the namespace is provided, otherwise it won't be able to find the Scripts object.

Comment: Thanks Brian i actually imported that before and a got a webgrease error (so assumed once again i was doing something wrong!)
Then found the following 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619255/
upgrading-webgrease-to-version-1-3-0-gets-me-error
So i'll run through the fixes suggested and see where i end up.
Thanks again

Comment: adding Optimization. in front of my Scripts call fixed my code, thank you!