# Upgrading WebGrease to version 1.3.0 causes error only on production server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5, webgrease

First off, answers to this question,do NOT solve my error:

[Upgrading WebGrease to version 1.3.0 gets me error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619255/upgrading-webgrease-to-version-1-3-0-gets-me-error)

I have the following bindingredirect on my production server:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

I have the following DLL's on my production server that are required for the Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework:

1. System.Web.Optimization.dll 1.0.0.0 (this is NOT pre-release version)
2. Antlr3.Runtime.dll 3.3.1.7705
3. Webgrease.dll 1.3.0.0

I am getting the following error:

`Could not load file or assembly 'WebGrease, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

I have checked the GAC, I have deleted all Temporary ASP.NET folders, I have tried removing the `newVersion` attribute from my config `<bindingRedirect>`. I am not sure what is telling ASP.NET to look for WebGrease 1.0

Comment: I have the exact same scenario and the same problems! Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: Figured my issue out and provided answer below.

Comment: This did fix my issue! Thanks so much! I marked your answer as the one! lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally figured out why this was not working for me despite other users saying that it was working for them.

I had the following binding redirection in my web.config file to force the `System.Web.Optimization` assembly to use the newer version instead:

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">

    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>

</configuration>
```

It was just like other users had, but it didn't work. Then I used the fusion log viewer (Fuslogvw.exe) to figure out more information and discovered that the binding process didn't even look at the redirect instruction.

Finally figured out that there must *not* be an XML namespace on the root  ... . If I remove the following from my `<configuration>` element it works: `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0"`

Also, just make sure you have the following XML namespace specified on the `<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">` element.

Finally!!

Comment: But if I remove the xmlns from my configuration line, my transforms from my web.release.config don't replace the values.  Why would this break that?  Is there a way to get both the transformations and the project to work?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem. I have a solution with different projects within. 
I have disinstalled Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization and WebGrease from all projects, and deleted manually all bin and obj folders.

Then I have installed Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization only in the project that need this package.

At this point I have deleted all files from packages folder.

When I had opened Visual Studio again it had started to reinstall all packages from scratch.

In the end I did a git-diff and this was the result:

```
$ git diff App.config
diff --git a/App.config
index ceec0aa..8937482 100644
--- a/App.config
+++ b/App.config
@@ -18,7 +18,7 @@
       </dependentAssembly>
       <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
-        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
+        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
       </dependentAssembly>
     </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>


$ git diff Web.config
diff --git a/Web.config b/Web.config
index 7287953..f196254 100644
--- a/Web.config
+++ b/Web.config
@@ -106,7 +106,7 @@
       </dependentAssembly>
       <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
-        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
+        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
       </dependentAssembly>
     </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>


$ git diff myproj.csproj
diff --git a/myproj.csproj b/myproj.csproj
index 12987d0..a214bf7 100644
--- a/myproj.csproj
+++ b/myproj.csproj
@@ -24,6 +24,7 @@
     </SccAuxPath>
     <SccProvider>
     </SccProvider>
+    <WebGreaseLibPath>..\packages\WebGrease.1.5.2\lib</WebGreaseLibPath>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
     <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
@@ -47,8 +48,8 @@
     <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
-    <Reference Include="Antlr3.Runtime, Version=3.3.1.7705, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processo
-      <HintPath>..\packages\WebGrease.1.3.0\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
+    <Reference Include="Antlr3.Runtime">
+      <HintPath>..\packages\Antlr.3.4.1.9004\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
     <Reference Include="Kendo.Mvc">
       <HintPath>..\Dll\kendo\Kendo.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
@@ -84,9 +85,8 @@
       <Private>True</Private>
       <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.4.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
-    <Reference Include="System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, pr
-      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
-      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Optimization.dll</HintPath>
+    <Reference Include="System.Web.Optimization">
+      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.2\lib\net40\System.Web.Optimization.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
     <Reference Include="System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processor
       <Private>True</Private>
@@ -129,9 +129,8 @@
       <Private>True</Private>
       <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.0.20710.0\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
-    <Reference Include="WebGrease, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchite
-      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
-      <HintPath>..\packages\WebGrease.1.3.0\lib\WebGrease.dll</HintPath>
+    <Reference Include="WebGrease">
+      <HintPath>..\packages\WebGrease.1.5.2\lib\WebGrease.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
   </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
@@ -760,7 +759,6 @@
     <Content Include="Views\Home\Index.cshtml" />
     <Content Include="Views\Shared\Error.cshtml" />
     <Content Include="Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml" />
-    <Content Include="Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml" />
     <Content Include="Views\Web.config" />
   </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
@@ -800,6 +798,7 @@
       <Generator>RazorGenerator</Generator>
       <LastGenOutput>index1.generated.cs</LastGenOutput>
     </Content>
+    <Content Include="Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml" />
   </ItemGroup>
   <PropertyGroup>
     <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
```

In particular, both App.config and Web.config had these differences:

```
       <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
-        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
+        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
       </dependentAssembly>
     </assemblyBinding>
```