# Cannot start default project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm trying just to create and start a blank project in ASP.Net MVC 4. But it throws an error in my face. I must say this didnt happen before I have updated VS with SP 3. I tried to repair installation, but it didnt help. And now I get this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'WebGrease, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Any idea, what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `WebGrease` in your project. You could achieve this by going to `Tool> Library Package Manager> Manage Nuget packages for solution` and than search `webgrease` at online category.

Comment: Did it, it is installed. I have also uninstalled and reinstalled it - same result

Comment: Try to put this in your webconfig : <dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.0.0" newVersion="here you put the latest version"/> </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>

Comment: Look, all these values are by default there, and it doesnt work

Comment: Try this too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866676/upgrading-webgrease-to-version-1-3-0-causes-error-only-on-production-server